# Best way to do simple API calls between Django server and android application?

Tags: django

I'm building a system where I store a Member model on a Django server, one of the attributes of Member is score which is what I want to change using API calls. My question is what would be the best way to do this? I looked into the Django REST framework but it seems a bit overkill for what I'm trying to do. I've been trying to pass the necessary information through the url using regular expressions but I'm unsure if it will work. Outline of what I need is below

- iOS/Android app makes request sending pk and score to add to total
- server updates appropriate model instance and returns True/False to app depending if save was successful

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by this quite dirty solution:

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:member_id>/<int:score_to_add>/', views.update_score, name='update_score'),
]
```

---

### views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Member


def update_score(request, member_id, score_to_add):
    member = Member.objects.get(pk=member_id)
    member.score += score_to_add
    try:
        member.save
        return HttpResponse("True")
    except:
        return HttpResponse("False")
```

---

Also you can respond with Json. Here is alternative views:

### Alternative views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Member


def update_score(request, member_id, score_to_add):
    member = Member.objects.get(pk=member_id)
    member.score += score_to_add
    try:
        member.save
        return JsonResponse({'status': True})
    except:
        return JsonResponse({'status': False})
```

---

But i think Django Rest Framework is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view to return `JsonResponse`. Take example of polls [app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/) in django and convert a post view to return a JSON response.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Choice, Question
# Need to disable csrf here
@csrf_exempt
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    # If you want Json requests Or you can use
    # received_json_data=request.POST if you are using normal form data request.
    received_json_data=json.loads(request.body)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=received_json_data['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # If failed
        return JsonResponse({'result': False})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return JsonResponse({'result': True})
```

Although It works but I would still recommend using DRF because what you are doing needs proper REST API and DRF eases a lot of pain points.